# Fetching Single Event From a Firebase Realtime Database Child

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble fetching data from a child node in a Firebase Realtime Database reference. I'm uploading a job request detail node to my logged in customer reference, however when I try to fetch the node, my controller won't read it and display it on the screen. Is it because I have to set my fetch API function to fetch the most recent job request detail node that was recently added by doing `.childAdded` instead if `.value`? Or am I doing something wrong when I call the fetch function in my controller itself? The reason why I ask is because I try to print jobRequest in my `fetchCustomerJobRequest()` and it doesn't print. Also, the reason why I have a question mark at the end of my `var jobReuest: JobRequest?` is because I initiate it in my `FindEmployeeJobRequestController` for the first time through the app, if that's correct too? Thank you in advance!

**Database Reference Setup**

[image]

[image]

**JobRequest Model**

```
struct JobRequest {
    
    let uid: String
    let fullname: String
    let username: String
    let address: String
    let firstDateAndTimes: String
    let secondDateAndTimes: String
    let thirdDateAndTimes: String
    let timeConstraints: String
    let jobDescription: String
    
    init(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        self.uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String ?? ""
        self.fullname = dictionary["fullname"] as? String ?? ""
        self.username = dictionary["username"] as? String ?? ""
        self.address = dictionary["address"] as? String ?? ""
        self.firstDateAndTimes = dictionary["firstDateAndTimes"] as? String ?? ""
        self.secondDateAndTimes = dictionary["secondDateAndTimes"] as? String ?? ""
        self.thirdDateAndTimes = dictionary["thirdDateAndTimes"] as? String ?? ""
        self.timeConstraints = dictionary["timeConstraints"] as? String ?? ""
        self.jobDescription = dictionary["jobDescription"] as? String ?? ""
    }
    
}
```

**Services API**

```
struct CustomerService {

static func fetchCustomerJobRequest(completion: @escaping(JobRequest) -> Void) {
        
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        REF_CUSTOMERS.child(uid).child("job-request-details").childByAutoId().observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
            let jobRequest = JobRequest(dictionary: dictionary)
            completion(jobRequest)
        }
        
}

}
```

**FindEmployeeJobRequestController**

```
// MARK: - Properties

var jobRequest: JobRequest? {
   didSet {
      configure()
   }
}

// MARK: - Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
        
   fetchCustomerJobRequest()
}

// MARK: - API

func fetchCustomerJobRequest() {
    CustomerService.fetchCustomerJobRequest { jobRequest in
        self.jobRequest = jobRequest
    }
}

// MARK: - Helper Functions

fileprivate func configure() {
        
    guard let jobRequest = jobRequest else { return }
    let viewModel = JobRequestViewModel(jobRequest: jobRequest)
        
    fullnameDetailsLabel.text = viewModel.fullname
    usernameDetailsLabel.text = "@" + viewModel.username
    addressDetailsLabel.text = viewModel.address
    firstDateAndTimeDetailsLabel.text = viewModel.firstDateAndTimes
    secondDateAndTimeDetailsLabel.text = viewModel.secondDateAndTimes
    thirdDateAndTimeDetailsLabel.text = viewModel.thirdDateAndTimes
    timeConstraintsDetailsLabel.text = viewModel.timeConstraints
    jobDescriptionDetailsLabel.text = viewModel.jobDescription
        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't do what you expect it to do:

```
REF_CUSTOMERS.child(uid).child("job-request-details").childByAutoId().observeSingleEvent(of: .value)
```

Calling `childByAutoId()` it generates a new unique location, that you then call `observeSingleEvent` on. But since you don't write anything to this location, there will never be any value for the listener to get.

So the `snapshot.value` will be `nil` in the callback, and in fact `snapshot.exists()` will be `false`.

Comment: Oh okay sweet, thank you! Instead of me using `childByAutoId()`, I removed it and `.value`, and inserted `.childAdded`